# How to operate on a single character in an enumerated char list in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Let's say I want to pass an enumerated char list through a combinator like `filter` in order to remove all a's like so:

```
'abc' |> Enum.filter(fn ch -> ch != 'a' end)
```

This won't return the expected result since the enumerated characters are in fact code points, here 97, 99 and 99. So the predicate could be expressed like `ch != 97` or `<<ch::utf8>> != "a"` to achieve the desired result.
Is there a better, more intuitive, way of expressing the predicate in this case?

Comment: I think Sasa's answer is pretty much the canonical/idiomatic way that most Elixir developers would code something like you outline above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `?` for this:

```
iex(1)> 'abc' |> Enum.filter(fn ch -> ch != ?a end)
'bc'
```

Comment: How would you write if the predicate is a Regex? E.g. `String.match?(*what here?*, ~r/[bc]/)`? <<ch::utf8>> or something else?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You want to get all chars that match the regex? If yes, I'd go with Regex.scan(~r/[bc]/, "abcbd"). Notice double quotes - Regex works only with binary strings. If you have a charlist, you can simply convert it to a binary via to_string/1.

Comment: My question was how you would convert a code point to a string when the `?a` option is not available as in the case you want to match with a regex. But maybe this is not a very common case.

Comment: Well, you could always do something like [codepoint] |> to_string. But as said, if you need to regex match individual chars, then I'd just do a Regex.scan over the entire string.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it the other way round:

```
'abc' |> Enum.filter(fn ch -> [ch] != 'a' end)
```

Although I prefer the usage of `?a`, and I much prefer the usage of binaries over character lists.